# Multi-threaded ray tracer significantly faster under Mavericks than Yosemite

Tags: multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch, raytracing

I'm writing a path tracer (ray tracer) to teach myself swift programming. Ray tracing is perfectly suited for parallelization because one can render each pixel independently. Here's how I set up my main loop, which allows for 8 threads.

```
var group:dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()
var queue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)
let lockQueue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("lockQueue", nil)
var semaphore:dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(8)

for every_pixel {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue) { () -> Void in

    let pixelColor = castRayAndIntersectObjects()

    dispatch_sync(lockQueue, { () -> Void in
        PutPixelOnBitmap(pixelColor);
    })                

    dispatch_group_leave(group)
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

After installing OS X Yosemite, I noticed a huge performance drop. What used to take 28 seconds to render under Mavericks, now takes 70 seconds on my quad-core macbook pro. Activity monitor shows that Mavericks is using 750% of my CPU, while Yosemite is only using 200% of the CPU. It's as if Yosemite is only able to run two threads at a time.

I'm using the -O (fastest) optimization level for swift, and I'm running the same exact swift executable on both operating systems.

If I modify my code to be a single threaded application, I get the same render time in both operating systems. So it seems to be a threading problem.

Did I set up multi-threading correctly? I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if I discovered a problem with Yosemite.

**More information (November 16, 2014):**

When I run the profiler, I see that the threads are locking on something, and that's where most of the time is spent on Yosemite.

On Mavericks, the profiler doesn't show __psynch_mutexwait and __psynch_mutexdrop, and that's why it runs significantly faster. So the question is why would something lock on Yosemite, and why does it not lock on Mavericks?

Comment: By using GCD you're relegating the thread creation and control to GCD, allowing it to create however many threads it feels is appropriate, and then (using your semaphore) artificially limiting how many tasks get put into the queue at any given time.  For more precise control over thread creation you might want to take a look at `NSOperation` or `NSThread`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely going to give that a shot, and I'm very curious to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: What happens if you take out the semaphore? With that there you're re-doing something that is one of GCD's major "areas of expertise" (i.e. knowing the best way to schedule tasks given the resources available, etc).

Comment: I rewrote the code so that it uses NSOperationQueue(). There's no more semaphore. Each thread just renders 1/8th of the screen, and there are 8 threads. The Yosemite problems still exists. It's pretty interesting.